# How to create a menu bar item that will launch an app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

Ok, I have created a little utility with AppleScript and used Automator to turn it into an application (MyApp.app). I would like to create a Menu Bar item (menulet, menu extra) that simply launches MyApp.app when you click on it.

I understand I need to create some kind of .menu file that goes in /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras folder.

I have Xcode setup, but not really sure where I need to start. All my googling has turned up is how to add and remove existing menulets already in the Menu Extras folder.

Any hints, tips, tutorials or code appreciated!

EDIT: I do NOT want to run the AppleScript from the little Script Menu Bar item... I want a separate menu bar item that will launch the application.

EDIT: I am talking about the Menu Bar up in the top right corner, not the Dock.

EDIT: I want to be able to create a shortcut or a quick launch button to an application, so that one click on the icon in the menu bar will launch the application. I do not want or need any drop down menus associated with the menu bar item ... one-click = launch application.

Comment: I assume you mean that you want to do this programatically?

Comment: @Bill If you mean write a program to do it then yes. But how else would you do it?

Comment: You would just drag it onto there. I assume you're talking about the dock? If not then sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: No not the dock.. I am talking about the Menu Bar up in the top right corner where the clock is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a status item - see [Status Bar Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/StatusBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000073i).  An older (Xcode 3, but there isn't much to it) tutorial can be found [here](http://www.sonsothunder.com/devres/revolution/tutorials/StatusMenu.html).

Comment: This was the first answer and seems to have most of the information I would need, however it does still not explain how to make a .menu file that goes in the CoreServices/MenuExtras folder.

Comment: Menu Extras are a private Apple thing - the documented NSStatusItem class doesn't quite have all of the features.  You should stay away from the /System folder, in any case.

Comment: So would I create a separate application, that when run, it will create a Menu Bar item (as part of itself), and then clicking on that Menu Bar item will launch the other application that I want?

Comment: Yes - you could do something like add it to your login items so that it starts running immediately after logging in.  It wouldn't necessarily need to be a separate application, it could be a part of your application that does its thing when the status item is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

**Step-by-step :**

1. Set `Application is agent (UIElement)` to `YES` in your in `info.plist` file
2. Get [UKLoginItemRegistry](http://zathras.de/angelweb/blog-ukloginitemregistry-zero-one.htm) from Uli Kusterer's site, if you want the menu to show up at LogOn (**optional;** but that's the way you'll most likely want to do it)
3. Implement an NSMenu (with the items you need) in your XIB and connect it as an outlet (`statusMenu`) to your main App Delegate
4. Set the `Status Bar Menu` in your `AppDelegate.m` file, like this :

---

```
- (BOOL)isAppSetToRunAtLogon {
    int ret = [UKLoginItemRegistry indexForLoginItemWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    return (ret >= 0);
}

- (void) runAtLogon
{
    [UKLoginItemRegistry addLoginItemWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] hideIt: NO];
}

- (void) removeFromLogon
{
    [UKLoginItemRegistry removeLoginItemWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {

    if (![self isAppSetToRunAtLogon])
    {
        [self runAtLogon];
    }

    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];

    NSImage* statusImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOUR_STATUS_MENU_ICON" ofType:@"icns"]];

    [statusImage setSize:NSMakeSize(20, 20)];

    [statusItem setImage:[statusImage retain]];

    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
}
```

And... that's it! :-)

Comment: ok, a little more complex than I had hoped... where do I set the application name that I want to run when I click the icon in the menu bar?

Comment: @jsherk Ooops, I didn't actually understand what you meant above. You don't set any application name... anywhere... what the above code does is to setup a menu in the status bar... that's all. What the menu items do, will be defined by whichever actions you connect to them (via Interface Builder), as usual.. ;-)

Comment: Don't use UKLoginItemRegistry. It uses the old, [deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html) LoginItemsAE implementation; the modern, supported ways (there are two) are documented [in the Daemons and Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html).

Comment: I do not want menu items (no drop down list) ... just a single click (the first click) on the icon will launch an application that would be specified in the code somewhere before compiling.

Comment: @jsherk: Then don't give the status item a menu. Set the status item's target and action instead.